# help with regex -- require AM/PM substring at end

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using php's preg_match to get a named subgroups from a string. I'm parsing user-generated date/time strings into well-formatted date/time tokens.

Here's my regex

```
~(?P<month>\d?\d)(/|-)(?P<day>\d?\d)(/|-)(?P<year>\d\d\d?\d?) +(?P<time>[\d: +((A|a)|(P|p))(M|m)]+)~i
```

And it correctly parses dates like

```
01-17-10 09:30 pm
2/1/2010 06:19am
```

into their constituent parts. However, it accepts `02/11/2010 06:19`, with no am/pm string, which I'd like it not to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks to user stereofrog for writing the original regex for me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using the character class `[\d: +((A|a)|(P|p))(M|m)]` for your time expression. This character set describes just one character and not a sequence with a defined pattern.

Try `(?P<time>\d\d?:\d\d *[ap]m)` instead:

```
~(?P<month>\d\d?)(/|-)(?P<day>\d\d?)(/|-)(?P<year>\d\d\d?\d?) +(?P<time>\d\d?:\d\d *[ap]m)~i
```